# PDO SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error, match

```
$MYSQL->bind('search_query', $search_query);
        var_dump($search_query);
        $query = $MYSQL->query("SELECT * MATCH (`post_title`, `post_content`) AGAINST (`:search_query` IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) FROM
                                    {prefix}forum_posts
                                    WHERE
                                    MATCH (`post_title`, `post_content`) AGAINST (`:search_query` IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);");
```

Nothing special in this query and the var_dump returns the right value of $search_query but I get evertime this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (`post_title`, `post_content`) AGAINST (`?` IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) FROM' at line 1

Do you know why this happens?

PS: I'm using a PDO-class so it is a bit differnent PHP syntax.

Comment: Forgot a comma before the first `match`

Comment: Thanks. Stupid error :D